# ASP.net DropDownList Inside Modal Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

I have issue here, inside my modal window got DropDownList as below

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group that">
              <asp:Label ID="lblBrand" CssClass="col-sm-2 this" runat="server">Brand</asp:Label>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <asp:DropDownList BackColor="#FFFFFF" CssClass="ddl" runat="server" ID="dropDownListVendor" DataValueField="brandID" DataTextField="brandName" AutoPostBack="true">
                       <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Choose a Brand..">
                  </asp:DropDownList>
```

**When i select the item in DropDownList, the Modal window will dismiss automatically.
How to prevent this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropDownList is configured as `AutoPostBack="true"`

As the result, the page posts back to server whenever DropDownList's selection is changed.

If you do not want DropDownList to post back to server, set `AutoPostBack="false"`

*Other than that, there is not enough information to answer your question.*

Comment: thank you. you solve my issue because i set the AutoPostBack = "true" before. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutoPostBack="true"` if you use UpdatePanels

Please find the example below:

(I Used 2 UpdatePanels for demonstration)

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("$('#Div1').modal('show');")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.[GetType](), "RunModalScript", sb.ToString(), False)
End Sub

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1"
                    runat="server"
                    CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                    Text="Open" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <div class="modal fade" id="Div1" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                            <Triggers>
                            </Triggers>
                            <ContentTemplate>

                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="test" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Item 3"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In my application I had to do extra stuff when a user selected an option from the list.

Also make sure that the 2nd UpdatePanel sits inside the `<div class="modal-body">`,
the UpdatePanel stops the page from refreshing (and hiding the Modal).

This is an old problem but this was a recent problem that I ran into and I wanted to share my solution.

Best Regards.